# Joomla! Quickstart package manual

Tags: database, joomla

I made some custom template and I still struggling with the most significant problem, how could I make a quickstart?

All the information what I found, doesn't helped me, including (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqG6Z8nhyBU), which is briefly:

1. Copy the designed database
2. Delete configuration.php from copied root
3. Copy default Joomla! Installation folder to copied root
4. Export sql.file from original database to copied installation/sql/msql
5. Rename that to sample_data.sql
6. Upload whole content to the server
7. Install as a usual Joomla! site

All the time I getting: 
**Error: the XML response that was returned from the server is invalid.**
in this reason I have to skip this message) when I select install sample data in my Joomla! pack installation. My template not appears as deafult and the places of module postions these are messages for e.g:

**Warning: DB reports: DB function failed with error number 1146
Table 'masolat.jos_sobi2_language' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT * FROM `jos_sobi2_language` ORDER BY `sobi2Lang` in C:\wamp\www\masolat\components\com_sobi2\config.class.php on line 2534**
...and so on.....

So prorbaly the whole process that I've made is false. That's why I would like ask you some help.

Have you any idea, how can I accomplish without any kind of Joomla! copy/restore extension? 
Short guide, review, link, explanation will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!
Regards: Nehogymar

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can install Joomla, the way that you described or the easy way for non-programmers.

Try to install joomla the easy way, There is very good explanation in Joomla documentation. try: http://help.joomla.org/content/view/39/132

There is also a excellent guide for installing Joomla on WAMP: 
http://www.compassdesigns.net/joomla-tutorials/how-to-install-joomla-15

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to make a copy of a Joomla website to install is to use Akeeba Backup. It makes a nice ZIP package with all of the files, settings, and database with a nice install script. I have a base install with all of the extensions I use to speed up configuration time.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606